# How can I use a private conda channel in my Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, conda

I want to create Docker container of my Python app using Docker for Windows. However, my conda environment also uses a package from a private conda channel. When I try to add the channel in my Dockerfile, I get a `404` error message (file not found). How can I make this work?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest

# Install custom channel
RUN conda config --add channels fico-xpress
RUN conda config --set custom_channels.privateName file://[...]/conda/channels

# Create the environment
COPY environment.yml /tmp/environment.yml
RUN conda env create -f /tmp/environment.yml

# Pull the environment name out of the environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate env" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the files over to the docker image
COPY app.py ./app/app.py
ADD app ./app

# Run the app
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo "streamlit run app.py" > ~/.bashrc

# Show which port to use
EXPOSE 5000
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: it can't find the file because it isn't in the current directory so `COPY` in your channel file

Comment: Any `file://...` URL will be interpreted in the context of the image; unless you `COPY` the content into the image it will be inaccessible.  Also note that many common Docker paths don't read `.bashrc` or similar dotfiles, and you're missing the default `CMD` that should get run when the container starts.

Comment: So I should copy the entire channel into the image to use it?